# Unexpected token else Android Studio

Tags: android, if-statement, razorpay-andoid-sdk

This my code about authentification, but I do not understand why when I run my code "else" display
"Unexpected token".

```
username = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername_id);
     motdepasse = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword_id);
     signin  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn_id);


    signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view)
      {
         if (username.getText().toString().equals("admin") && motdepasse.getText().toString().equals("admin"));
          Intent intention = new Intent( Login.this, ATM.class);
          startActivity(intention);
      }
      else {
          Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    });
}
```

`

I am expectin to resolv my coding  problem

Comment: Typo. The `;` at the end of the `if` line should be a `{` instead.

Comment: Count the `{}`, your `else` is outside the `onClick` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like- check if condition and onclick method.

```
username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername_id);
     motdepasse = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword_id);
     signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn_id);


    signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (username.getText().toString().equals("admin") && motdepasse.getText().toString().equals("admin")) {
                startActivity( new Intent(Login.this, ATM.class));
             } else {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```